# The /e modifier is deprecated

Tags: php, preg-replace

Estou com esse erro ao gerar um um relatório que fiz aqui, será se alguém pode me ajudar.

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: 8192
>
> Message: preg_replace(): The /e modifier is deprecated, use >preg_replace_callback instead
>
> Filename: includes/functions.php
>
> Line Number: 74

Comment: pq vc usa o modificado `e`? como a mensagem diz ele foi depreciado e também é perigoso. Poderia colocar a linha onde ele se encontra, acredito que o código deverá ser reescrito.

Comment: Recomendo que leia : [Manual de como NÃO fazer perguntas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/14213) relacionado a sua : [Não postar o seu código ou a sua mensagem de erro](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5484/14213)

Comment: Por essa mensagem de erro, talvez possa chutar que você usou o Codeginiter. Confirme para mim, para eu alterar a tag, por favor.

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com o Manual do PHP:

> *PHP 5.5.0*: O modificador `e` está obsoleto. Use `preg_replace_callback()` como alternativa.
>   Veja a documentação [PREG_REPLACE_EVAL](https://php.net/manual/pt_BR/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php#reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.eval) para adicionais informações sobre riscos de segurança.

Provavelmente seu PHP está usando alguma biblioteca que foi escrita para versões anteriores do PHP 5.5.

Talvez a solução fosse remover a notificação do `E_DEPRACATED`

```
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED);
```